# How to override the ItemsSource defined for an ItemTemplate?

Tags: wpf, binding, itemtemplate

I use an Item Template to define how the rows of my grid must be displayed. The grid definition (simplified) shows that the item template source is `GridRows` (a collection of rows) :

```
<grid ...>
   (...)
   <ScrollViewer 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GridRowItemDataTemplate}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding GridRows}" />
   </ScrollViewer>
</grid>
```

So far, so good.

In the item template, the textbox is bound to `ImportZoneName`, which resolved of course to `GridRows[i].ImportZoneName`, and this is exactly what I want :

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GridRowItemDataTemplate">
   <Grid>
      <TextBlock {Binding ImportZoneName}" />
      <ComboBox 
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModelingTypeValue}" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding ModelingTypes}" />
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now the problem : I also want to bind the combo box to an other property (`ModelingTypes`) of my view model. This property is not linked in any way to GridRows. How can I tell WPF to override (or forget) the item template source?

Many, many thanks !

BTW, I did not find yet a simple guide for these simple binding cases... If anyone have a link to such a guide, I will bless him/her forever :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `DataContext` of the parent list like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GridRowItemDataTemplate">
   <Grid>
      <TextBlock {Binding ImportZoneName}" />
      <ComboBox 
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModelingTypeValue}" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ModelingTypes, 
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                           AncestorType=Grid}}" />
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Replace `Grid` with the type of the grid you are using (not sure which it is, not evident from the question), as long as its `DataContext` has the property `ModelingTypes`

Comment: Yes, yes, that's it ! I tried something similar before but I had another bug: Value and Name were not declared as properties... Damn ! Now it works perfectly. Thanks again :)